# WAS 8.0(beta version) | unable to parse the MBean descriptor file

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-7, websphere-6.1, websphere-8

Getting this exception unable to find the reason why? Has anybody seen this before? I am running my application in WAS 8.0(beta version).

> > com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.DescriptorParseException: ADMN0001W: The service is unable to parse the MBean descriptor file
> >     com/ahold/ers/dcr/common/jmx/mbeans/impl\SpringContextMBean.xml.  at
> >     com.ibm.ws.management.descriptor.MBeanDescriptorManager.loadDescriptorFile(MBeanDescriptorManager.java:411)
> >       at
> >     com.ibm.ws.management.descriptor.MBeanDescriptorManager.getDescriptor(MBeanDescriptorManager.java:190)
> >       at
> >     com.ibm.ws.management.MBeanFactoryImpl.activateMBean(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:458)
> >     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: mbeans\AlertHibernateManagerMBean.xml

The forums on the net say i would need to change the JDK and point it to the one provided with WAS 8.0(beta version). Didn't understand this either. I am trying to migrate JavaEE 5 compliant code to WAS 8.0(beta version) (Java EE6). It should happen smoothly i guess as JVM is backward compatible. I hope i wouldn't need to recompile my code with Java EE6 just to make it work with WAS8. Is my understanding correct?